# jQuery: How to restrict special characters which are repeated/ continued

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a input field, which is business name. In this how can I apply special conditions or naming conditions like:

Stack && overflow -- wrong

Stack & overflow -- correct

Stack overflow''s -- wrong

Stack overflow's -- correct

Stack () overflow -- wrong

Stack & overflow -- correct

Stack overflow/s -- wrong

Stack overflow's -- correct

like this, what I have specified "wrong", those names are not meaningful, I need meaningful names, for this how to restrict special characters or unrelated characters from the name. Please share  if you have any solutions for it.

Comment: Please share your research and code attempts to solve this yourself. This isn't a free code writing service and you are expected to have researchd this before asking

Comment: You can use `regex` to avoid special characters in names

Comment: Can you use custom validation which can count and validate this special characters for your need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for name validation
This regular expression will work for yor requirement

```
^([A-Za-z]{1,})(([ &]?[A-Za-z]{1,})*(['][A-Za-z]{1})?)$
```